# How to remove the first occurence of a repeated Character with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have been given the following string `'abcdea'` and I need to find the repeated character but remove the first one so the result most be `'bcdea'` I have tried to following but only get this result

```
def remove_rep(x):
    new_list = []
    for i in x:
        if i not in new_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    new_list = ''.join(new_list)
    print(new_list)

remove_rep('abcdea')
```

and the result is `'abcde'` not the one that I was looking `'bcdea'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which returns the first occurrence with the string:

```
def remove_rep(oldString):
    newString = ''
    for i in oldString:
        if i in newString:
            # Character used previously, .find() returns the first position within string
            first_position_index = newString.find(i)
            newString = newString[:first_position_index] + newString[
                first_position_index + 1:]
        newString += i

    print(newString)


remove_rep('abcdea')
remove_rep('abcdeaabcdea')
```

Out:

```
bcdea
bcdea
```

Comment: Shouldn't the o/p for `abcdeaabcdea` be `aabcdea`? as we just need to remove the first occurence of a character and keep the rest

Comment: The question description says so : How to remove the 'first occurence' of a repeated Character with python

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be to iterate in reverse order over the string, and keep track of all the characters seen in the string. If a character is repeated, we don't add it to the `new_list`.

```py
def remove_rep(x: str):
    new_list = []
    seen = set()

    for char in reversed(x):
        if char not in seen:
            new_list.append(char)
        seen.add(char)

    return ''.join(reversed(new_list))

print(remove_rep('abcdea'))
```

Result: `'bcdea'`

---

Note that the above solution doesn't exactly work as desired, as it'll remove all occurrences of a character except the last one; for example, if you have 2+ occurrences of a chracter and you only want to remove the first one. To resolve that, you can instead do something like below:

```py
def remove_rep(x: str):
    new_list = []
    first_seen = set()

    for char in x:
        freq = x.count(char)
        if char in first_seen or freq == 1:
            new_list.append(char)
        elif freq > 1:
            first_seen.add(char)

    return ''.join(new_list)
```

Now for the given input:

```
print(remove_rep('abcdeaca'))
```

We get the desired result - only the first `a` and `c` is removed:

```
bdeaca
```

Test for a more complicated input:

```
print(remove_rep('abcdeaabcdea'))
```

We do get the correct result:

```
aabcdea
```

Do you see what happened in that last one? The first `abcde` sequence got removed, as all characters are repeated in this string. So our result is actually correct, even though it doesn't look so at an initial glance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches with one small change in the `if` condition:

```
def remove_rep(x):
    new_list = []
    visited = []
    for i, item in enumerate(x):
        if item not in x[i+1:] or item in visited:
            new_list.append(item)
        else:
            visited.append(item)
    new_list = ''.join(new_list)
    print(new_list)

remove_rep('abcdeaa')
remove_rep('abcdeaabcdea')
```

Output:

```
bcdeaa
aabcdea
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace()` does that :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old
> replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the
> first count occurrences are replaced.

So basically :

```
"abcabc".replace('b', '', 1)
# output : 'acabc'
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
new_list = ''.join(new_list)
```

to

```
new_list = ''.join(new_list[1:]+[i])
```

(and figure out why! Hint: what's the condition of your `if` block? What are you checking for and why?)